# How do I properly acess the google speech to text api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-speech-api

I am trying to use the google speech to text api I already have my key set up but I do not know how to access the api I keep getting the error.

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
GOOGLE_KEY = ""
with sr.Microphone() as source:
print('Speak now')
audio = r.listen(source)
print("Time is over")

try:
    print("TEXT:" + r.recognize_google(audio,key= GOOGLE_KEY))
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
    raise
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
```

These are the errors I am getting
            , Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "/Users/bob/PycharmProject/grid/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 840, in recognize_google
response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bob/PycharmProject/grid/audio.py", line 11, in <module>
print("TEXT:" + r.recognize_google(audio,key= GOOGLE_KEY))
      File "/Users/bob/PycharmProject/grid/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 842, in recognize_google
raise RequestError("recognition request failed: {}".format(e.reason))
speech_recognition.RequestError: recognition request failed: Forbidden
```